# Divide data into datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a query that reurns me a result of 3500 rows. Each row is a 15 minute time record  period of a day:

```
             DATE          VALUE
     --------------------|-------
   1 |2016-10-21 10:00:00|  0
   2 |2016-10-21 10:15:00|  0
   3 |2016-10-21 10:30:00|  6
   4 |2016-10-21 10:45:00|  9
   5 |2016-10-21 11:00:00|  18
   6 |2016-10-21 11:15:00|  15
             .
             .
             .
 3500|2016-11-30 00:15:00|  0
```

I want to insert this query in a c# datagridview but i dont want an unique column, i want a column for each day.For example, in this query i get 40 day result, and i want a datagridview with a column for each day.

¿Anyone knows which is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: And if you have 365 days, you want 365 columns? And one row with values? Also your question is too broad - you either should ask for preparing data in required format, or you should have data and ask how to bind it to gridview

Comment: I would have thought you would be better off generating the output you need in the database first. Then return the data and bind to the grid.

Comment: No, the maximum number of columns that i will have is 40. Thats why i want it in columns.

Comment: Pivot the data in the SQL query https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410

Answer (score 0):

Something like that :

```
var query = new[] { new { Date = new DateTime(2016,10,21,10,0,0), Value = 6 },
                    new { Date = new DateTime(2016,10,21,10,15,0), Value = 9 },
                    new { Date = new DateTime(2016,10,30,10,0,0), Value = 18 }};
var groupedQuery = query.GroupBy(p => p.Date.Date, p => p.Value, (key, g) => new { Date = key, Value = g.Sum() });
var grid = new DataGridView();
var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = groupedQuery;
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
grid.DataSource = bs;
foreach (var item in groupedQuery)
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn { HeaderText = item.Date.Date.ToString() };
    grid.Columns.Add(column);
}
```